# Use variable from controller in view ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There is a model in my project

```
using System;

namespace Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels
{
  public class UsersPage
  {
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierFullName { get; set; }
    public bool ActionsAllowed { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I use my model in controller and set properties

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        var supplierOfUser = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
            //.Include(e => e.Supplier)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        string SupplierId = id.ToString();
        string SupplierFullName = supplierOfUser.FullName.ToString();
        bool ActionsAllowed = supplierOfUser.Active;

        return View();
    }
```

and then I need to use that in view, but I don't know how to get my properties in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `UsersPage` and assign the properties you already have to its properties, then pass the newly created `UsersPage` to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        var supplierOfUser = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
            //.Include(e => e.Supplier)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        var usersPage = new UsersPage();
        usersPage.SupplierId = id.ToString();
        usersPage.SupplierFullName = supplierOfUser.FullName.ToString();
        usersPage.ActionsAllowed = supplierOfUser.Active;

        return View(usersPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your controller action needs to send that model instance to the view like this:

```
return View(supplierOfUser);
```

You need this at the top of your view:

```
@model Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels.UsersPage
```

Then all you need to do is whereever you want to use your model in the view do:

```
@Model.SupplierFullName
```

If you want to use other properties in the view that you can place them into a dynamic ViewBag variable like this:

```
ViewBag.supplierOfUser = supplierOfUser.FullName.ToString();
```

and then on your view you can use this value like this:

```
@ViewBag.supplierOfUser
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help you with exact code as I don't know what you want to do on your view, this is a general idea of how you're supposed to pass and use your model in your view

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    var supplierOfUser = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

    var usersPage = new UsersPage
    {
        SupplierId = supplierOfUser.Id,
        SupplierFullName = supplierOfUser.FullName,
        ActionsAllowed = supplierOfUser.Active
    }

    return View(usersPage ); // <-- Send viewmodel to view
}
```

**VIEW**

```
// Declare model
@model Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels.UsersPage
...
//Use your model here at will
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)

...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
```

Comment: Why IEnumerable when he is getting FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your data from the controller to the view, you need to return the view with your model in parameter:

```
return View(supplierOfUser);
```

In your view, you'd also need to define the model:

```
@model YourModel
```

Note that you don't need to set your supplier info into other variables (only supplierOfUser is required).

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to establish a strongly typed model in the view:

`@model Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels.UsersPage`

Then, just reference the properties on the model, e.g.

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierFullName)`